# Как получить координаты вершин на babylon.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylon.js

Я отрисовываю куб с помощью **babylon.js** вот так:

```
var box = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("box", 2.0, scene, false, BABYLON.Mesh.DEFAULTSIDE);
```

Как получить координаты его вершин?

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы получить массив координат вершин объекта в babylon.js можно использовать следующее:

```js
a = box.getVerticesData(BABYLON.VertexBuffer.PositionKind)

var arrays = [], size = 3;
    
while (a.length > 0)
    arrays.push(a.splice(0, size));

console.log(arrays);
```

При этом мы получим координаты 24 вершин!!! Откуда это получилось:

В `WebGL`, чтобы отрисовать грань куба необходимо использовать два треугольника и режим `gl.TRIANGLE_FAN` при котором грань куба можно нарисовать имея всего 4 вершины (первые три вершины образуют первый треугольник, а второй треугольник образуется из следующей вершины, одной стороны предыдущего треугольника и первой вершины), итого получаем наше значение `4*6 граней = 24 координаты`.

Это конечно тоже много, но можно уже из полученного выбрать необходимы координаты.